# OnClickListener for Button is not being called

Tags: android, mongodb, retrofit2

I am using RetroFit 2.1.0 to post a device object to my MongoDB database:

```
public class Device extends Fragment {
    EditText deviceName;
    EditText numDevices;
    Button submitButton;
    private API api;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.master_view, container, false);

        deviceName = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.device_name);
        numDevices = (EditText)
                rootView.findViewById(R.num_devices);
        submitButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.submit_button);

        Retrofit retroFit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(getString(R.string.base_url))
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        api = retroFit.create(API.class);

        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                saveDevice();
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    public void saveDevice() {
        //THIS LINE OF CODE IS NOT RUNNING NOT SURE WHY?
        System.out.println("GOT INTO SAVE MASTER");
        DeviceModel device = new DeviceModel();
        device.setDeviceName(deviceName.getText().toString());
        device.numOfDevices(Integer.parseInt(numDevices.getText().toString()));

        Call<DeviceModel> deviceModel = api.createDevice(device);

        deviceModel.enqueue(new Callback<DeviceModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<DeviceModel> call, Response<DeviceModel> response) {
                System.out.print("Success" + response.code());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<DeviceModel> call, Throwable t) {
                System.out.print(t.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is my API.java:

```
public interface API {
    //Device endpoint
    @POST("device/insert")
    Call<DeviceModel> createDevice(@Body DeviceModel master);
}
```

I am using RetroFit 2.1.0 to save a device object to a MongoDB instance that is running on `http://localhost:3000`. When I hit the endpoint `http://localhost:3000/device/insert` on postman it saves the device JSON object to the DB.

But when I do it through the app using RetroFit it doesn't seem to work at all. Am I doing something wrong in the `saveDevice` method?

Comment: did you add INTERNET permission to your manifest file?

Comment: Is `onCreateView` being executed?

Comment: @MahdiNouri Ohh I forgot to do that. Thank you for reminding me... And also thyago Yes onCreateView is being executed since I see the fragment on the screen!

Comment: I added this in the Android.Manifest file: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` right before the opening `application` tag but it still doesn't seem to work. For some reason I just noticed that the `println` inside `saveDevice` isn't being called. That means my `onClickListener` is not working properly on the submit button. Since I also didn't get any error for INTERNET permission. Is my `onClickListener` setup properly?